# Using Django to store session variable, but session variable not appearing in chrome://settings/cookies

Tags: python, django, cookies, session-variables

I have tried to set session variables with both simply

```
request.session['test'] = id
```

and

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
s = SessionStore()
s['test'] = id
s.save()
```

Of course I've enabled the appropriate middleware.

```
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'
```

I feel I must be setting the session variable correctly because when I print things like

```
print request.session['test']
```

and

```
print s.session_key
```

I get the output I would expect.

What I don't expect to see is that when going to

```
chrome://settings/cookies
```

I don't see the cookies set with the session variables anywhere.

All I see is the session id and my csrf token

[image]

I thought I'd see a third cookie, the one I set with my session variable that was a key.

Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: Downvotes without explanation can appear cowardly to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Unless you have specifically set the session backend to use cookies, the data is stored in the database and only a key is stored in the cookie.

Comment: But that's just it. I don't even see s key when I go to chrome to find it at chrome://settings/cookies.

Comment: Well the second code wouldn't set a cookie because you've written directly to the store and there's no relation with the request. But the first would do.

Comment: Neither did in my case. I added a screenshot to show what I saw after setting session variables both ways.

Comment: Well sessionid is clearly there, I'm not sure what you think the problem is.

Comment: I thought that was just the cookie set when any session starts, not the one I set with my session variable. Sorry, I don't have much experience with this sort of thing.

Comment: It's the same thing: the session ID is the key for the session store.

Comment: OK, but then why do I get that sessionid even when I don't set the session variable?

Comment: For the same reason you just gave: the session ID is set at the beginning of the session.

Comment: Please bear with me as I am relatively new to this. I understand that a sessionid cookie is set for the user when the session has started. But then I would have thought that when I made a new session variable with `request.session['test']` there would have been yet another cookie that was encrypted and it would show in firebug.

Comment: I can't understand why you think that, or why my or Bogdan's explanations are not clear. The session data lives on the server in the session store; the only thing that gets set in the cookie is the singular key for that session.

Comment: So is nothing about a session variable stored as a cookie on the user's machine?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the session documentation:

> To use cookies-based sessions, set the SESSION_ENGINE setting to
>   "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies". The session data
>   will be stored using Django’s tools for cryptographic signing and the
>   SECRET_KEY setting.

So even if you set the right backend you wont get to see the cookie value. Is encrypted using the SECRET_KEY.

Comment: Sure, but should't I at least see the encrypted value as evidence that it was indeed set?

Comment: What you are seeing in the chrome inspector is the session id cookie. This points to a session that contains the variable set in the view.

Comment: OK, but then why do I get that `sessionid` even when I don't set the session variable?

Comment: The session is created when you visit the website, and contains basic info like the user id or the user type. In your view you added your variable test to the session. So you can retrieve it but the session id stored in the cookie does not change. It points to the same session that contains your parameter.

Comment: Please bear with me as I am relatively new to this. I understand that a sessionid cookie is set for the user when the session has started. But then I would have thought that when I made a new session variable with request.session['test'] there would have been yet another cookie that was encrypted and it would show in firebug.